# How to view a specific Google Groups post on mobile?

Tags: google-groups, mobile

When doing a Google search on my iPhone, I saw a result from Google Groups. However, on clicking the link it didn't load the target page but instead sent me to the "home page" of Groups: https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/m/#!overview

I've tried several times and it keeps doing it. I can't see a link for the non-mobile site, and Google doesn't show a cache for pages on mobile.

Is there anything else I can do?